# Usage of Obsolete class

Tags: c#

We were using class `'System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform'` in our project and now recently we started using resharper.  This throw waring Class `'System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform'` is obsolete: "This class has been deprecated. Please use `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform` instead. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202"

Is it good to update the code to new class or keep the existing as the system performs well.

Is there any disadvantages with this approach.

Comment: Check this [Migrating From the XslTransform Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f54faw.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warnings are just that - not an error, but something you should be aware of. If the code performs well enough now, feel free to leave it as is. Just know that the API may disappear in the future so you'll have to deal with it eventually if you upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Is good to update and don't use deprecated classes as it will go away in upcoming versions and you will have no choice but to update your code. So sooner to update is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XslCompiledTransform` class instead which is valid in .Net 4.6, e.g.:

```
var xsltCompiled = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform(enableDebug:true);
xsltCompiled.Load(stylesheetUri:xsltFile);
xsltCompiled.Transform(inputUri:xmlInputFile,resultsFile:anyOutputFile);
```